# Sufficient conditions of the curvature of a curve for the curve to be convex

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, convex-geometry

I have been reading about the 4 vertices theorem in differential geometry, I have a doubt, we know that the curvature of a convex curve fulfills the following:

$\kappa \ \text{is periodic}$

$\kappa \ \text{has at least 4 critical points}$

$\kappa\geq0$

$\int \kappa=2\pi$

The question I have is, are these curvature conditions sufficient for the curve to necessarily be convex? or is there a curve that serves to show that no, I would appreciate it if you could tell me.
First of all, Thanks

Comment: $\kappa$ here is *signed* curvature, of course. As long as the curve is embedded (no self-intersections), you're OK. I usually define convexity to be strict convexity, so then $\kappa>0$.

Comment: thank you, another question has arisen, the conditions that I mention above imply that the curve is closed and convex?  the convexity I think I have already seen clear that yes, but the closed is not clear to me

Comment: No, the fact that the curve is closed does *not* follow. You need $\int_0^L T(s)\,ds = 0$, where $T$ is the unit tangent vector. For all this stuff, you might look at section 3 of chapter 1 of my differential geometry text, linked in my profile.

Comment: perfect, thank you very much!